# Copy members of one struct to another C#

Tags: c#, struct

I want to copy members of one struct (GR) to another larger struct (FR)

```
    public struct gr
    {
        public double O,C,L;
        public bool isLastFRH, isLastFRL;
    }
    public gr GR;

    // Here I assign values to GR and then I want to copy all these values to FR

    public struct fr
    {
        public double O,C,L;
        public bool isLastFRH, isLastFRL;
        // it has more variables.
    }
    public fr FR;
```

Is it possible to be done without going one by one:

```
    FR.O = GR.O; // and so on...
```

Thank you

Comment: GR could be a superclass to FR.

Comment: You might consider AutoMapper: https://automapper.org/

Comment: @zerocukor287 OP is asking about struct - there is no inheritance possible (also indeed if you suggesting that those should be classes I agree - it's already outside of the recommended size of the structs and mutable structs are ... sub-optimal. But that is up to OP to decide)

Comment: Are you sure a struct with mutable fields is the right solution to your problem?

Comment: Performance is paramount that's why I want to use structs

Comment: Are you allowed to use `unsafe` code?

Comment: Yes it is possible, however unless you do a memory copy, every other solution will just be doing a member copy anyway, Also using automapper for this task is meh. In short just copy by members and move on

Comment: @TheGeneral, agreed. want faster code? code.

Comment: You could consider making a `struct gr` field inside `struct fr`, then you could just assign it.

Comment: I'm assuming it has to be a struct (probably because you are doing p/invoke?). If not, the `record` class is perfect as it gives you deep-clone by default. I have noticed you said "it must be struct for performance" - don't fall into the trap of thinking that structs are inherently faster or more performant than classes or records. It's what you do with them that matters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot subclass a struct in C#, so your best option is to create a new struct that uses the struct you want to copy. The `GR` property is a struct so it will be a copy of whatever you set it with.

In your `fr` class add the `gr` member:

```
public struct fr
{
   public gr GR;
   //add your unique props..
}
```

Now you can create `fr` and just set the `GR` property, it will copy.

```
var gr1 = new gr() {  //set all your properties.. };
var fr1 = new fr() { GR = gr1, ... //set all your fr specific props here };
```

Comment: Thanks. It´s a good option!

Answer (score 0):

Try using automapper, it allows you to create mappings easily. [see details](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html)

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<gr, fr>());


var mapper = new Mapper(config);
Fr model = mapper.Map<Fr>(gr);
```